# Why won't Xcode highlight all errors?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to migrate to Swift 3 and noticing some issues with Xcode. It won't highlight all errors in my files. Some files I open and I know there are errors there but it isn't highlighting them. Some files it does highlight them. This issue is very frustrating. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: swift intelisense doesnt work very well, and even worst if is latest swift. Only ObjC have proper intelisense

Answer (score 1):

No it´s not basically. This depends on that you have some errors that are shown first that you need to resolve before you can show other errors and so on.

Go to settings and and set "Continue building after errors" it will help you more errors and hopefully all of them.

[image]